# Array element problem in a derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I want to call the spherical Bessel and spherical Hankel functions of the first kind and save them in a table to later use the elements of the table. This is easily done by

```
    sphericalbessel[r_] = 
  Table[FunctionExpand[SphericalBesselJ[l, r]], {l, 1, 100}];

sphericalhankel[r_] = 
  Table[FunctionExpand[SphericalHankelH1[l, r]], {l, 1, 100}];
```

However, when I try to use the elements stored in the table to perform some computational steps like forming a derivative

```
abl[l_Integer, r_] = D[r*sphericalbessel[r][[l]], r];
abl1[l_Integer, r_] = D[r*sphericalhankel[r][[l]], r];
```

I run into problems. How can I effectively save these functions in a table to recall its elements later to perform other computational steps. I need these functions very often in my program which is why I found it most useful and efficient to call them once and save them in a table. Is there another maybe more efficient way?

[Edit]

When I do the following thing:

```
In:  D[r*sphericalbessel[r][[2]], r]

Out: -((3 Cos[r])/r^2) + ((3 - r^2) Sin[r])/r^3 + 
     r ((6 Cos[r])/r^3 + ((3 - r^2) Cos[r])/r^3 + Sin[r]/r^2 - (
        3 (3 - r^2) Sin[r])/r^4)
```

the derivative works for the second element of the table as requested, but I fail to do the general definition in another function as attempted above.

[Edit2]

Ok, seems as if I need to use a `If[]` condition in the definition of `abl[]`. Is this the 'correct' way or how could I store this functions more efficiently when it comes to computational time?

Comment: For defining your functions, use `SetDelayed` instead of `Set`

Comment: Alright, changed this. I defined now `abl[l_Integer, r_] := If[l < 101, D[r*sphericalbessel[r][[l]], r]];` . When I use `abl[1, r]` I obtain the correct derivative. Though, I want to use `abl[1, x/y]` and it says that x/y is not a valid variable. The problem is probably the derivative `D[]`. How can I adapt my definition in order to use `x/y` as an argument?

Comment: You shouldn't need the `If` statement. Also, to use the `x/y`, I used `Replace[abl[1,h], h->x/y, {1,5}]` which looks like what you're looking for.

Comment: Your function doesn't work for x/y because it tries to take the derivative of the function with respect to x/y. you could change your `abl` function to be `abl[l_Integer, r_, d_] := D[r*sphericalbessel[r][[l]], d];` where `d` is what you take the derivative with respect to

Comment: @J_Nat: I know about replace, though I have the feeling that this extremely slows down my computation as the variable h needs to be replaced in more than 10000 terms.

I do not quite get your last suggestion. I need to take the derivative with respect to r. If I introduce a new argument `d` the derivative is with respect to that variable which is wrong in my case.

Comment: If you need to take the derivative with respect to r, then you would just put `abl[1, r, r]`. I made that change because you were trying to use `x/y`, so you would have to do `abl[1, x/y, x]` or `abl[1, x/y, y]`. If you just need the derivative WRT r, then don't change it from what you originally had.

Comment: May I suggest instead of storing all the functional forms in the table, you simply define: `sphericalBessel[n_Integer, r_] := FunctionExpand[SphericalBesselJ[n, r]]`.  Then `D[sphericalBessel[3, n], n]` will do what you ask?